# How to fix the play framework exception on jenkins? (play.exceptions.CompilationException: "MY_ENUM_VALUE" cannot be resolved or is not a field)

Tags: java, jenkins, playframework

Application works well. But when I am trying to make some feature. Add some Enum value and then use him in future, there are appears Compilation error :

```
play.exceptions.CompilationException: MY_NEW_ENUM cannot be resolved or is not a field
17:51:07    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:256)
17:51:07    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:678)
17:51:07    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:522)
17:51:07    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:292)
17:51:07    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:428)
17:51:07    at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:604)
17:51:07    at play.Play.init(Play.java:308)
17:51:07    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:160)
```

Locally i fixed this problem. I run "play deps -clearcache and -sync. Then rebuild project in maven and error gone. But when i tried to make Build on jenkins this error appeared again but this time on jenkins. It is possible to resolve this problem? and how i can fix it?

Comment: May be you changes are not reflected in the jenkins code. Are you using any version control system like Git, Svn etc?

Comment: I am using gitlab

Comment: Then make sure your changes are pushed to the correct branch.

Comment: Just checked. All changes in correct Branch. As i said locally where the same problem, i think it is not problem with gitlab. But what it exactly and how to fix it i dont't know too